# Is it posible to use multiple values from a json list in a mysql where clause?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have this table filled with values, and it's all structured in JSON.

| PersonID | ValueID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | {"Values":[{"ID":1,"Value":true},{"ID":2,"Value":true}]} |
| 1 | 2 | {"Values":[{"ID":2,"Value":false},{"ID":3,"Value":true}]} |

So I was wondering if there was any way to query on the ID and value at the same time, so I etc. would be able to search for "ID":1 and "Value":true and then it would return the first row.

I've tried to use JSON_CONTAINS_PATH, JSON_CONTAINS, JSON_SEARCH but none of them takes into account that I want to search in a list, I have tried with the $.Values[0].ID and that returns the id but I need to loop all of them through in the where, else I would only search the first index of the JSON array.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: "Can anyone point me in the right direction? ==> 
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   PersonID,
   ValueID,
   x1.* 
FROM table1
cross join JSON_TABLE(table1.Value, 
   '$.Values[*]' COLUMNS( ID INTEGER PATH '$.ID',
                          Value INTEGER PATH '$.Value'
                        )) as x1
```

output:

| PersonID | ValueID | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7df5901d9ce723699aa9210973b96f10)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.value->'$.Values[0]' = JSON_OBJECT('ID',1,'Value',true)
```